# Non degenerate constraint qualification in Lagrange problems. Can anyone help?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Let us assume we want to find local extremal of a function of two variables $f(x,y)$. Also, let us assume that we have three equality constraints. This means that the Jacobian matrix, which is $2 \times 3$ can not have rank $3$ as the number of constraints. So the NDCQ conditions are never satisfied and it does not make any sense to compute the Lagrange system. How do we proceed here?

---

My attempt:
If we have $3$ constraints I think we have two cases: either the constraint set is the null set because the constraint are nit compatible between them (their intersection is the empty set) or we have two linearly independent constraints, that means that we can reduce the lagrange problem to a problem where we have only two constraints, for example. Am I correct? Do you have any example?

Comment: The set-up you're proposing should never occur. Even with two independent constraints, you'll be left with a discrete set of points. With three, you will have no points whatsoever satisfying the constraints. Working in the plane, Lagrange multipliers is applicable and interesting only with one constraint.

Answer (score 0):

There are 8 possibilities. Suppose the constraints are g(x,y)-0, h(x,y)=0, u(x,y)=0.
Then $$ \nabla g=[0,0] or \nabla f = \lambda \nabla g $$ 
and  $$ \nabla h=[0,0] or \nabla f = \alpha \nabla h $$
and  $$ \nabla u=[0,0] or \nabla f = \beta \nabla u $$
At each of these 8 possibilities, all 3 constraints must be satisfied.

Comment: But what about the NDCQ ? They require the rank of the matrix to be 3 but it can not be three.